# android wear duplicate sensorEventListener

Tags: android, wear-os, android-sensors, sensormanager

I'm developing an Android Wear App which register Heart Rate from start until the moment the user stop it touching a button, so i don´t unregister the listener on function onStop or onDestroy.

The problem is when i return to the Wear Menu and open the app again. In that moment the app register the listeners again and get all measures duplicated. I tried to unregister the listeners on function onStart and onRestart but it didn´t work.

Here is my code:

```
    ...

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
    Sensor mHeartRateSensor;
    SensorManager mSensorManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Sensor and sensor manager
        mSensorManager = ((SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE));
        mHeartRateSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();  
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mHeartRateSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mHeartRateSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
    /*
    I need the listeners are active, so i can't unregister it
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        this.mSensorManager.unregisterListeners(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }*/

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        //Get heart rate and accuracy
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {
        //
    }

    /*on click listeners*/
    ...
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a boolean variable named `mIsRegistered`,set its default value to false.and when you want to register,firstly check the value,if false ,do register,if true,dont't register again.